# amp lightbox scrollable not valid

Tags: amp-html

I added the recently announced new attribute "scrollable" to the amp-lightbox tag, and it works great!
But the AMP-Validator actually doesn't accept exactly this attribute.
Does anybody know why?

Comment: You may want to follow this [issue tracker](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/6754), the validator is still being updated on the changes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! So it seems to be just a question of time ...

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem but the solution was simple.

add a div in the amp-lightbox for global container. and on it put overflow:auto ;)

that work :D